# React Native Environmental Variables in VS App Center

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, react-native-config

I am struggling with getting `.env` variables to show up in my React Native app, when compiling with VS App Center. I am using `react-native-config`, and have a local `.env` file that work when developing locally, but when I build with VS App Center, the predefined environment variables in the console, are available via the app.

I have added the following variables in the console:
[image: screenshot of app center varibles]

Then, I have created a `appcenter-post-clone.sh` in the root directory of the project:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Creating .env file"
cat > ./.env <<EOL
API_URL=${API_URL}
GOOGLE_API_KEY=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}
EOL
```

However, no .env is created - there is nothing in the build log with `Creating .env file`, so I am confused on what the best path is here. Does anyone have any guidance here on how to read `.env` values with App Center builds?